# Intercept SMS message

Tags: android

So I have an application, which should make a phone call when receiving a specific message from a specific phone number.
The broadcast receiver works on a Samsung Galaxy Tab2, on Android 4.0.3, but the messages are not received any more by Go SMS Pro, if no phone call has to be made.
When running the application on Samsung Galaxy S2 (Android 4.0.3), the broadcast receiver seems to not intercept at all the messages and Go SMS Pro works correctly.
I have tried to use "abortBroadcast" and "clearAbortBroadcast", but they had no effect.

Here is the code for my broadcast receiver:

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
/** The Action fired by the Android-System when a SMS was received.
 * We are using the Default Package-Visibility */

private static final String SMS_EXTRA_NAME = "pdus";


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Message received", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("");
    if(intent.getAction().equals(Consts.ACTION)) {

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if(bundle != null)
        {
            //Get received SMS array
            Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) bundle.get(SMS_EXTRA_NAME);

            for ( int i=0; i < smsExtra.length; i++)
            {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])smsExtra[i]);
                String body = sms.getMessageBody().toString();
                String address = sms.getOriginatingAddress();
                if(address.equals(Consts.COPCI_NUMBER)) {
                    sb.append(body);
                }
            }
        }
        if(sb.toString().equals(Consts.TRIGGER_MESSAGE))
        {
            Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel: " + Consts.POLI_NUMBER));
            dial.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(dial);

        }
        else {
        }

    }
}
```

}

And this is the AndroidManifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.Parcare"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver android:name="com.example.Parcare2.SMSReceiver" android:priority="100">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: Does your application have any activities? If not, it will remain in the "stopped state" after installation and your `BroadcastReceiver` will never get called.

Comment: So I added an empty activity (finishes when pressing back) and now the receiver is called on all devices. The problem now is when making the phone call. The phone call is immediately stopped when Go SMS Pro also intercepts the message. Why is this happening? If I make the activity from somewhere else (e.g. from the empty activity), the phone call is initiated and performed correctly

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Go SMS Pro and I don't understand exactly what you are describing. You are starting an Activity when the SMS arrives. It may be possible that Go SMS Pro is also starting an Activity and that is conflicting. What you could try, to see if it helps, is to replace `context.startActivity()` with `context.getApplicationContext().startActivity()` in your `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Another thing you could try is to lower the priority of your `BroadcastReceiver` so that it gets called **after** Go SMS Pro. To do this you need to add `android:priority="-100"` to the `<intent-filter>` inside the `<receiver>` tag. The priority setting you have on the `<receiver>` tag is ignored and should be removed. You might need to play with the priority (it can be any number between -1000 and 1000) to see if that changes anything.

Comment: If you search on Stackoverflow for "Go SMS Pro" there seem to be a lot of issues with that application conflicting with other applications.

Comment: "Go SMS Pro" is the SMS application used by the person for which I try to make this application, so it has to be considered. It uses maximum priority: "2147483647", as my broadcast receiver only receives the event if I use this priority, but it inhibits Go SMS. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a way yet to make both receivers intercept the SMS.

Comment: If you aren't aborting the broadcast, "Go SMS Pro" should also get the SMS. However, people are saying that if "Go SMS Pro" gets the broadcast first, it will abort the broadcast so that you won't receive it.